# Expression/phrase for "more or less"

Tags: translation, phrase-request

I once asked how to say the equivalent of the English expression "more or less" to an Italian speaker (non-native) and they replied that it could most accurately be translated as: "Più meno"

But I have never been able to verify this with any second source as accurately conveying the meaning of the expression. What is an appropriate phrase that conveys this sentiment in an informal tone, regardless of the closeness to the actual translation in English?

Comment: Almost: the correct phrase is “*più o meno*” (which is literally, word by word, “more or less”).

Comment: You can also say “suppergiú” (or “su per giú”) or “pressappoco” (or “press’a poco”), which have the same meaning as “piú o meno”.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As already stated in comments, "più o meno" is the best way to translate "more or less", which is its literal meaning.
However, there are some alternatives, like:

- Press'a poco
- All'incirca
- A grandi linee

But the second and third ones may sound more formal and, in some cases, might not perfectly fit in the sentence.